# How to serve in Vert.x rest api using jersey, static resources and sockjs exposed event on one port

Tags: jersey, vert.x

Can i run in Vert.x :  vertx-jersey for rest api and Vert.x Web with SockJSHandler on one port?

In the result i would like to have "localhost:8080/api" for rest api,  "localhost:8080/ebus" for sockjs exposed messages and "localhost:8080/"  to serve javascript front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only you can, that's the usual way it's done.

```
    final Pattern chatUrlPattern = Pattern.compile("/ebus/(\\w+)");
    final EventBus eventBus = this.vertx.eventBus();

    final Router router = Router.router(this.vertx);

    // Or wherever your static content is
    router.route("web/*").handler(StaticHandler.create());        

    this.vertx.createHttpServer().websocketHandler(ws -> {
        final Matcher m = chatUrlPattern.matcher(ws.path());
        if (!m.matches()) {
            ws.reject();
            return;
        }
        /* Your code here */
    }

    // Your Jersey code here, for example:
    vertx.runOnContext(aVoid -> {

        // Set up the jersey configuration
        // The minimum config required is a package to inspect for JAX-RS endpoints
        vertx.getOrCreateContext().config()
                .put("jersey", new JsonObject()
                        .put("port", 8080)
                        .put("packages", new JsonArray()
                                .add(HelloWorldEndpoint.class.getPackage().getName())));

        // Use a service locator (HK2 or Guice are supported by default) to create the jersey server
        ServiceLocator locator = ServiceLocatorUtilities.bind(new HK2JerseyBinder(), new HK2VertxBinder(vertx));
        JerseyServer server = locator.getService(JerseyServer.class);

        // Start the server which simply returns "Hello World!" to each GET request.
        server.start();

    });
```

Comment: Thanks, i was to stacked with JerseyVerticle , you pointed me good direction.